# In Javascript how can I make a second if statement run within another if statement?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've set up some JS (using jQuery library), and it's not working as I'd expected it to. I am fairly new to Javascript, so I did a lot of looking around online to find out if running an `If` within an `If` was possible, and came to the conclusion it is.

It should be self-explanatory what the code is doing. In a nut shell ... it's testing for a boolean in a custom attribute on the drop-down selector (the "primary `if` statement"); AND, within those two primary results (true, or false), it's testing for three different screen widths (the "secondary `if` statement").

It validates, with no errors, on https://beautifytools.com/. So syntax doesn't appear to be the issue.

My JS:

```
 var widthMobile;
 var widthTablet;
 var widthDesktop;
    $(window).resize(function(){
            if (($(window).width()<651) && ($(window).width()<981)) // mobile
            {
                widthMobile = true;
                widthDesktop = false;
                widthTablet = false;
                console.log('Mobile:'+widthMobile);

            } else if (($(window).width()>=981)) // Desktop
            {
                widthTablet = false;
                widthMobile = false;
                widthDesktop = true;
                console.log('Desktop:'+widthDesktop);

            } else if (($(window).width()>=651) && ($(window).width()<981)) // Tablet
            {
                widthTablet = true;
                widthMobile = false;
                widthDesktop = false;
                console.log('Tablet:'+widthTablet);
            }
    });
    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pa_size').change(function() {
    console.log('selector changed');    
        if ($("#pa_size").find("option:selected").attr('stock-status') == "false") { //out of stock
        
            $("#sticky-atc-bar .single_add_to_cart_button").hide();
            console.log('button hidden');
            if (widthDesktop) { // Desktop
                $("#sticky-atc-bar").css({"height": "120px"});
                $("#sticky-atc-bar .et_pb_module.et_pb_wc_add_to_cart").css({"margin-top": "-27px"});
                console.log('Desktop and in stock');
            } else if (widthTablet) {
                $("#sticky-atc-bar").css({"height": "115px"}); // Tablet
                $("#sticky-atc-bar .et_pb_module.et_pb_wc_add_to_cart").css({"margin-top": "10px"});
                console.log('Tablet and in stock');
            } else if (widthMobile) {
                $("#sticky-atc-bar").css({"height": "190px"}); // Mobile
                $("#sticky-atc-bar .et_pb_module.et_pb_wc_add_to_cart").css({"margin-top": "12px"});                
                console.log('Mobile and in stock');

            }
            
        } else { // In stock
        
//          $("#sticky-atc-bar .woocommerce-variation-availability").hide();
            $("#sticky-atc-bar .single_add_to_cart_button").show();
            
      console.log('button shown');
      
            if (widthDesktop) { // Desktop
                $("#sticky-atc-bar").css({"height": "100px"});
                $("#sticky-atc-bar .et_pb_module.et_pb_wc_add_to_cart").css({"margin-top": "-17px"});
                console.log('Desktop and NOT in stock');
                
            } else if (widthTablet) {
                $("#sticky-atc-bar").css({"height": "115px"}); // Tablet
                $("#sticky-atc-bar .et_pb_module.et_pb_wc_add_to_cart").css({"margin-top": "10px"});
                console.log('Tablet and NOT in stock');

            } else if (widthMobile) {
                $("#sticky-atc-bar").css({"height": "150px"}); // Mobile
                $("#sticky-atc-bar .et_pb_module.et_pb_wc_add_to_cart").css({"margin-top": "10px"});                
                console.log('Mobile and NOT in stock');

            }
        }
    }).trigger("change");
});
```

The HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sticky-atc-bar">
  <div id="inside-container">
    <select id="pa_size" class="" name="attribute_pa_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
      <option value="1kg" stock-status="true" class="attached enabled">1kg - $75.90 &nbsp;- (In Stock)</option>
      <option value="2kg" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">2kg - $119.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
      <option value="3kg" selected="selected" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">3kg - $174.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
      <option value="5kg" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">5kg - $262.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
      <option value="10kg" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">10kg - $482.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
      <option value="20kg" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">20kg - $823.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt disabled wc-variation-is-unavailable">Add to cart</button>
  </div>

<div class="test">
TEST
</div>
  <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_wc_add_to_cart">
    <p>
      some content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you will see, it is running the primary `if` statement fine, but not the secondary `if` statements within primary one.

I've set up a jFiddle for it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/inspirednz/q09t8k2d/66/).

#### Two questions

1. What's causing my code not to work?
2. Even if we correct my code, is there a different and better way to go about getting the outcome I want?

Comment: Try `console.log` prior to testing in `if` conditions. And check if the values that you are expecting are actually there.

Comment: Given that all you're doing is setting css properties, you should use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) instead. Then most of your code will disappear.

Comment: @TheWhiteFog - Thanks for that suggestion. I now see the issue is that I've used `$(window).resize(function(){` but that is only triggering if and when the browser size changes. Hence, my variables end up undefined until the browser is resized.

Comment: @Nick - The reason I've not done this using media queries, is because I need to change some CSS dynamically, and I need the change to differ depending on what the screen width is. The purpose of the jQuery is to handle the dynamic changing of CSS. If nothing dynamic was required, yes, it would be much simpler to handle it all in media queries.

Comment: @inspirednz you could achieve that result by using media queries and toggling a class on the elements that changed the appropriate css elements

Comment: by the way, it's nothing to do with jQuery ... `if` is javascript ... `jQuery` is just a javascript library primarily useful for making things run on internet explorer

Comment: @Nick, okay. Yes, it hadn't even crossed my mind to change the classes. Going to need to rethink this. Brain is a bit numb from having gone so far down the rabbit hole with the approach I was taking. :-)

Comment: @Nick - roughly speaking ... to go about this using media queries, and to make it dynamic, am I correct in thinking I'd make use of `window.matchMedia()`, combined with the JS I'm using to check the custom attribute value (which is what's adding the dynamic element into this whole scenario)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modified JS fiddle. Its better to use Media Queries, you can do plenty with that. Only use JS if css has been explored to its limits.

But that said, you mentioned you want to change classes dynamically, so I set this up for you to see how you could do that https://jsfiddle.net/7u1gcmL5/8/

Also just to help you get familiar with JQuery, show you how to simplify some of your code. I didnt not want to do it all but at least show you a direction you can go.

PS you have to paste code to link to jsfiddle but this shows how you can reduce code

```
function checkWindowSize(){
    let windowWidth = $(window).width(); // keep it short
    if(windowWidth>=981){
       return 'widthDesktop';
    } else if((windowWidth>=651) && (windowWidth<981)){
      return 'widthTablet';
    }
    return 'widthMobile'; //reduce your ifs and else as much as you can
 }
```

As mentioned by Trincot, you dont need to add **&& (windowWidth<981)** in the statement as its always true.

Comment: The condition `(windowWidth<981)` will always be true where you have it.

Comment: How so, not sure I understand? its with a && so only true if windowWidth>=651 is true.

Comment: The previous `if` already made sure that `window >= 981` is not true... so what would you expect `window < 981` to evaluate to then?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Yeah its not needed, good spot, I copied the conditions from the first example. Will amend.

Comment: @Sprep - this is exceedingly helpful. I was very aware my code attempt was a "hack" at best (lol), and I greatly appreciate seeing how to go about it in a far cleaner and more efficient way. Learning a lot from what you've taken the time to post. I have a question. To incorporate the `windowClass` into taking actions based on its value (`widthDesktop`, etc.), do I simply test for its value using `if` statements such as those I set up, or is there a more efficient way to go about that now?

Comment: Assuming using `if` statements is okay way to continue the rest of the code, I've modified my screen size based actions code, as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/inspirednz/L3sr8uyh/4/

Comment: Glad I could help, here is a https://jsfiddle.net/xbyd9atm/16/ showing a more CSS approach. Code is also more simple to read. Its not perfect, spent a few mins on it but you can take it further.

Comment: even more simplified. https://jsfiddle.net/uy258mo9/16/ just add a class if out of stock, let css handle everything else.

Comment: Thank you @Sprep. Both of those Fiddles are helpful ... as it's helping me gain more understanding of working with JS / jQuery. The second one, has really simplified things, and makes a LOT more sense than the tangent I went on originally. I was happy to go on the tangent, as it got me learning more about JS. But this last code example has shown me how I could have thought about this from a completely different angle. Thank you, and also thanks to Nick for pointing me in that direction too. :-)

Comment: No worries there, happy coding. Glad to help